# Basic program returning an unexpected value

Tags: c, floating-point-exceptions

I've written a program to do some basic operations on a long number from the user. Depending on whether the final product ends in a 0 or not, the program printfs "valid" or "invalid". I tried it with some 10 digit numbers and it worked fine, but anything with 11 digits or higher just returns "Floating point exception". Do I need to change my syntax in some way to accommodate longer numbers?

```
int main(void)
{
    long i = 0;
    long b;
    int m = 10;
    int n = 1;
    long number = get_long("Number?\n");
    do
    {
        long a = number % m;
        b = number - a;
        long c = b % (m * 10);
        long d = c / m;
        long e = d *2;
        if (e < 9)
        {
            i = i + e;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + (e - 10 + 1);
        }
        
        {
            m = m * 100;
        }
    }
    while (b > 0);
    do
    {
        long a = number % n;
        b = number - a;
        long c = b % (n * 10);
        long d = c / n;
        long e = d *2;
        if (e < 9)
        {
            i = i + e;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + (e - 10 + 1);
        }
        
        {
            n = n * 100;
        }
    }
    while (b > 0);
    int f = i % 10;
    if (f == 0)
    {
        printf("valid");
    }
    else
    {
    printf("invalid\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your previous question I have already suggested to use strings for input. It will remove the "length" restriction and will also make your code much simpler.

Comment: Maybe use `double`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. would I need to replace all ints and longs with string, or just the user's input?

Comment: The maximum value of a long is a 10-digit number.

Comment: It's `2,147,483,647`

Comment: Use `long long` and you can get up to 20 digits.

Comment: @Barmar ah excellent- that's perfect, thanks.

Comment: Supplying concrete data from a test run would have helped to understand the problem. What's the nonsense `while (b > 0);`?

Comment: @U.Windl That is the end of a `do { /*...*/ } while (...);` loop.

Comment: @thebusybee Sorry, stupid me; that's why I always write "} while (...);" in one line.